# Listbox equivalent in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, listbox, nstableview

Is there an equivalent to the Tkinter listbox widget (or of any other language) in Swift? I already tried the NSDocumentView, but it is apparently not thought for what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a UITableView. Each row will be represented by a UITableViewCell.

Comment: Can you use UITableView on Mac OS or only on iOS?

Comment: @V.Boersch-Supan `UI` methods and classes come from UIKit which is only for iOS. For OS X use the AppKit (Cocoa) ones, like NSTableView.

Comment: @Eric D Ok, I'll give that a try